# Flex/bison "non-C++"

Tags: bison, lex

I was wondering about existence of flex/bison, that works with different languages than C++. All I was able to google was people developing their own parser working similar to flex/bison, but I am looking for a program that still uses .y and .l files with similar syntax, but it uses something different than C++.

Comment: In the Java world it's antlr : https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/an-introduction-to-language-lexing-and-parsing-with-antlr

Comment: Here's a general list : http://catalog.compilertools.net/lexparse.html

Comment: @rusi: i don't believe that list has been updated in about 15 years. Wikipedia's list is probably better but all such lists need to be used with caution.

Comment: @rici why not put the Wikipedia link? I just commented what google gave for "LR parser generator". If it were a better resource I'd have made it an answer. To OP : If you ask wrt specific languages you'll get more pointed answers

Answer (score 1):

GNU Bison does support other languages than C++ though being limited to C/C++/D/Java. ([reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Decl-Summary.html#index-_0025language)).

> **Directive: %language "language"**
>
> Specify the programming language for the generated parser. Currently supported languages include C, C++, D, and Java. language is case-insensitive.

You can find a detailed explanation of constructing Java parser with bison on its [official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Java-Parsers.html)

Unfortunately, flex does not seem to support other languages.
There are projects ([JLex](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Eappel/modern/java/JLex/), [JFlex](https://www.jflex.de/)) that share syntax with `lex`.

As you can see, there are not many.